How to build this .py env (Error installing socketio)
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.exp
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyUnicode_FromUnicode
      build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\netifaces.cp312-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
Failed to build netifaces
ERROR: Could not build wheels for netifaces, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I installed socketio using python version 3.12.2 a while ago and the project worked fine now when i upgraded the version to 3.12.3 it is giving me this error

#update
The issue has been resolved the error was in the way i was installing the library the correct pip command for connecting to websockets with python is
(pip install python-socketio)
